# Wordpress Multiple Category Search

Tags: categories, search, customization

From few months I am digging into wordpress for multiple category search options, and finally came up with this.

I just found that wordpress allows multiple tags, which means that if in your URL you type this

```
http://yourblog.com/tag/tag1+tag2
```

then it will return all your posts with having tags, tag1 **AND** tag2

but if you type

`http://yourblog.com/tag/tag1,tag2`

then it will return all the posts having tag1 **OR** tag2

Same thing now works for categories also

`http://yourblog.com/category/cat1+cat2` and `http://yourblog.com/category/cat1,cat2`

But this only works for category and tags, I am trying it for search option.

Till now I coded where this URL is working(which means it will search HTML only in the category id 114),

`http://yourblog.com/?s=html&cat=114`

In this URL, the **comma separator** works very well, but not the **+**

I mean to say

`http://yourblog.com/?s=html&cat=114,115`

works very well but

`http://yourblog.com/?s=html&cat=114+115`

doesn't works.

Can anyone help me in this? I really want this to work

Still awaiting

Comment: Can anyone help me in this??????????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that in a url the '+' sign is equivalent to a space so that's how PHP sees it.

If you use an action on `parse_request` you can make this work like so:

```
add_action( 'parse_request', 'category_search_logic', 11 );
function category_search_logic( $query ) {

    if ( ! isset( $query->query_vars[ 'cat' ] ) )
        return $query;

    // split cat query on a space to get IDs separated by '+' in URL
    $cats = explode( ' ', $query->query_vars[ 'cat' ] );

    if ( count( $cats ) > 1 ) {
        unset( $query->query_vars[ 'cat' ] );
        $query->query_vars[ 'category__and' ] = $cats;
    }

    return $query;
}
```

The above will get category ids passed in with '+' in between them by splitting them on a space which is what PHP sees in the $_GET parameter.

If we have more than one item in the array it must be an 'and' style search so we can pass the array from splitting on the space into the `'category__and'` query var which returns posts in all the specified categories.

Comment: I think you need a hats off from my side, this actually worked, at last now I can have multiple category search on my sites

Really really thankful  to you :)

Comment: @ntechi My pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `http://yourblog.com/?s=html&cat[]=114&cat[]=115`

BTW, why don't you use a hook link `pre_get_posts` to filter your search? It would be much easier than tweaking the search URL.

Comment: Itried the `cat[]=114&cat=115` but not working, and can you explain me what to do with `pre_get_posts` I am not getting you

Answer (score 1):

The solution suggested by @sanchothefat is OK, but leads to problems when pagination is used.
For example, you have url like domain.com/?s=&cat=1+2. When you click on page 2, the URL become domain.com/?s=&cat=1+2 but redirect_canonical() defined in wp-includes/canonical.php tries to modify url to domain.com/?s&cat=12 which is not the same...
I found easier to me to rewrite category_search_logic() rather investigate redirect_canonical() logic and apply additional filters to it.

This is my way to buypass the canonical logic:

```
function category_search_logic( $query ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_GET['categories'] ) )
        return $query;

    // split cat query on a space to get IDs separated by ',' in URL
    $cats = explode(',', $_GET['categories'] );

    if ( count( $cats ) > 1 ) {
        unset($_GET['categories']);
        $query->query_vars[ 'category__and' ] = $cats;
    }

    return $query;
}
```