# Multiple Category Search

Tags: categories, search, customization

I'm trying to create a search feature that will allow users to enter a search term and select a couple of categories. The script searches a single category just fine, but when I add more than one I hit a roadblock.

My code is as follows:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
    <input type="text" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Search...':this.value;" value="Search..." name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories('taxonomy=product_cat&id=make&child_of=15&show_option_all=Select Make...'); ?>
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories('taxonomy=product_cat&id=model&child_of=21&show_option_all=Select Model...'); ?>
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

As I was searching around I discovered: [Wordpress Multiple Category Search](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27158/wordpress-multiple-category-search), which seems to do exactly what I want...however I'm not sure how to incorporate the suggestion.

I'm pretty sure you add the following to your functions file:

```
add_action( 'parse_request', 'category_search_logic', 11 );
function category_search_logic( $query ) {

    if ( ! isset( $query->query_vars[ 'cat' ] ) )
        return $query;

    // split cat query on a space to get IDs separated by '+' in URL
    $cats = explode( ' ', $query->query_vars[ 'cat' ] );

    if ( count( $cats ) > 1 ) {
        unset( $query->query_vars[ 'cat' ] );
        $query->query_vars[ 'category__and' ] = $cats;
    }

    return $query;
}
```

But, how do I incorporate this into the search form? I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm lost...anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution...

My functions page now looks like:

```
<?php
    class dropdown extends Walker_CategoryDropdown {
        function start_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args) {
            $pad = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $depth * 3);
            $cat_name = apply_filters( 'list_cats', $category->name, $category );
            $output .= "\t<option class=\"level-$depth\" value=\"".$category->slug."\""; 
            $output .= '>';
            $output .= $pad.$cat_name;
            if ( $args['show_count'] )
                $output .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;('. $category->count .')';
            if ( $args['show_last_update'] ) {
                $format = 'Y-m-d';
            $output .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;' . gmdate($format, $category->last_update_timestamp);
            }
            $output .= "</option>\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

My form now looks like:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
    <input type="text" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Product Search...':this.value;" value="Product Search..." name="s" id="s" class="left" />
    <input type="image" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/images/icosearch.png" id="searchsubmit" value=""/>
    <?php
        wp_dropdown_categories(
            array(
                'child_of' => 426,
                'class' => 'styled',
                'id' => 'make',
                'name' => 'make',
                'show_option_all' => 'Make...',
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'walker' => new dropdown
            ))
    ?>
    <?php
        wp_dropdown_categories(
            array(
                'child_of' => 427,
                'class' => 'styled',
                'id' => 'model',
                'name' => 'model',
                'show_option_all' => 'Model...',
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'walker' => new dropdown
            ))
    ?>
</form>
```

My search page now looks like:

```
<?php
    $tmp[]=$_GET["model"];
    $tmp[]=$_GET["make"];
    $product_cat=array();                                          
    foreach($tmp as $v) {
        if($v!="0")
        $product_cat[]=$v;
    }
    if(count($product_cat)>0) {
        $product_cat="&product_cat=".implode(",",$product_cat);    
    }
    else {
        $product_cat="";
    }                                                           
    $query=query_posts("s=$text".$product_cat);
    $count =count($query);
    if ($count == 0) { 
        echo 'No Results'; 
    }
    elseif ($count == 1) { 
        echo ''.$count.' Result'; 
    } 
    else { 
        echo ''.$count.' Results'; 
    } 
?>
```