# Search functionality with multiple categories

Tags: categories, search

Good day fine wordpress gurus,

I'm having a tough time writing a function that handles the search in a couple of user-selected categories. The way I'm presenting the categories is through the old get_categories method and I'm iterating through the array in order to build a category tree with checkboxes (client requirement).

So what I need is a hint of how to get the search in such a way that it includes the search term and the cat_ID's that the user selected in order to bring the relevant results.

PS: I already checked out [Wordpress Multiple Category Search](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27158/wordpress-multiple-category-search) this link, and I didn't find anything useful. so please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like something [Relevanssi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/) could handle. With Relevanssi, you'd have the checkboxes to choose the categories. Then, you'd write a function to hook on 'relevanssi_modify_wp_query' filter, where you'd read the checkboxes and convert them to a comma-separated list of category ID's. That you would store in $wp_query->query_vars['cats'] and hey presto, Relevanssi gives you relevant results in those categories.

I think the same idea might work with default search, actually, but instead of 'cats' you'd use 'cat' and instead of 'relevanssi_modify_wp_query' you'd need another way to modify the $wp_query.

Comment: Yes, thank you Mikko, I finally went down the relevanssi route and I'm setting the value for cats through some javascript which builds an array from the values of the checkboxes.