# Keyword search in multiple categories

Tags: categories, customization, search

I've spent a day or so on this now and I'm turning to the community for assistance.

Firstly, I am trying to achieve something like this post:

[Wordpress Multiple Category Search](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27158/wordpress-multiple-category-search)

In my theme template, I have a custom search form:

```
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
<fieldset>

    <input type="text" name="s" value="" placeholder="Search..."></input>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="search_category_section">
    <?php
        $args = array('parent' => 0);
        $categories = get_categories($args);

        echo '<div class="search_category_section">';

        foreach ($categories as $category) {

        $thecatid = $category->cat_ID;
            echo '<div class="categorylist"><div class="parent_category_list_item"><input id="', $thecatid, '" type="checkbox" name="category_name" value="', $category->slug, '"><label for="', $thecatid, '">', $category->name, '</label></input></div>';
            $childcats=get_categories(array('parent' => $thecatid));
                foreach($childcats as $c) {
                echo '<div class="child_category_list_item"><input id="', $c->cat_ID, '" type="checkbox" name="category_name" value="', $c->slug, '"><label for="', $c->cat_ID, '">', $c->name, '</label></input></div>';
            }
        echo '</div>';
        }
    ?>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

So, let's say for example I search for "keyword", and I select two checkboxes, "category A" and "category B". I have two posts, one in each category. Each of those two posts has that keyword in it. After hitting the submit button it generates the following URL:

mydomain.com/?s=keyword&category_name=category-a&category_name=category-b

What this is currently doing is presenting me with one result - that is, one post from category B with that keyword in it.

What I'm actually looking for is this result:

mydomain.com/?s=keyword&category_name=category-a,category-b

Whereby I get all posts in all categories, with that keyword in it.

I've looked high and low, and while I've found results where others were trying to achieve a similar thing, none of their solutions worked for me.

This is all part of a learning curve for me. I have found [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-filter/) which looks like it will do what I want, but as you've all probably been in this situation whereby "I wish I could do this myself so that I understand better how the mechanics behind Wordpress" work I hope you'll appreciate the question.

Thanks in advance, if anything isn't clear or I've left vital info out let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked for me.

Preethis answer almost got there, but no data was getting set. I needed to find a way of accessing the data in the array, and I used implode to do it.

So here is my final code that enabled me to create a search form that loops and displays categories, allows the user to do a keyword search via any number of categories, and display results IF the keyword exists in any of the categories selected:

I created a **searchform.php** file in my theme file and included the following HTML:

```
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
<fieldset>

    <input type="text" name="s" value="" placeholder="Search..."></input>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="search_category_section">
    <?php
        $args = array('parent' => 0);
        $categories = get_categories($args);

        echo '<div class="search_category_section">';

        foreach ($categories as $category) {

        $thecatid = $category->cat_ID;
            echo '<div class="categorylist"><div class="parent_category_list_item"><input id="', $thecatid, '" type="checkbox" name="category_name[]" value="', $category->slug, '"><label for="', $thecatid, '">', $category->name, '</label></input></div>';
            $childcats=get_categories(array('parent' => $thecatid));
                foreach($childcats as $c) {
                echo '<div class="child_category_list_item"><input id="', $c->cat_ID, '" type="checkbox" name="category_name[]" value="', $c->slug, '"><label for="', $c->cat_ID, '">', $c->name, '</label></input></div>';
            }
        echo '</div>';
        }
    ?>
        </div>
</fieldset>
```

and then, my **functions.php** has the following code:

```
<?php
    function advanced_search_query($query) {
        if($query->is_search()) {
            $get_the_category_name = $_GET['category_name'];
            if (isset($get_the_category_name) && is_array($get_the_category_name)) {        
            $catnames = implode(",",$get_the_category_name);
            $query->set('category_name', $catnames);
            return $query;
            }
        }
    }
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'advanced_search_query');
    ?>
```

if you do:

```
var_dump($get_the_category_name);
```

You'll get:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(22) "category-a" [1]=> string(25) "category-b" }
```

Run implode() on that

```
string(48) "human-element-analysis,latent-defects-check-list"
```

Stick that string in a variable, set it in query as category_name, win.

Thanks again Preethi for putting me in the right direction, and hope the above helps anyone looking to do the same!

Answer (score 2):

**let’s start by defining an HTML search form:**

```
<form method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
<fieldset>
<input type="text" name="s" value="" placeholder="search&hellip;" maxlength="50" required="required" />
<p>Refine search to posts containing chosen tags:</p>
<?php
// generate list of categories
$tags = get_categories();
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo 
        '<label>',
        '<input type="checkbox" name="taglist[]" value="',  $tag->slug, '" /> ',
        $tag->name,
        "</label>\n";
}
?>
<button type="submit">Search</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

**Add this to functions.php**

```
function advanced_search_query($query) {

    if($query->is_search()) {

        // tag search
        if (isset($_GET['taglist']) && is_array($_GET['taglist'])) {
            $query->set('tag_slug__and', $_GET['taglist']);
        }

        return $query;
    }

}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'advanced_search_query', 1000);
```

Comment: Hi Preethi - as it happens I was talking to one of my colleagues who recommended sticking it in an array, and it looks you beat him to it. Cheers for the reply, I will update accordingly.